Discounted payoff where S is risk-neutral and K is real-world
We are busy pricing a derivative (I think!) where the stock price is assumed to follow the usual GBM process. The strike however is not constant and follows a company's EBITDA.
Our theory is that: There is no market for a company's EBITDA and therefore we cannot setup a replicating portfolio. Something along the lines of an incomplete market (I am more than fuzzy on all the technical theory).
At the risk of being scolded I have two questions:

Is this theory correct and does this mean that we cannot obtain a "risk-neutral" option price?

If we are forced (by accounting requirements) to "value" this thing, what options (pardon the pun) do we have?


Hopefully a storm in a tea cup.
TLDR;
I work for "one of the big four" audti firms and the departments are playing hot potato with this valuation. We have previously valued these instruments in the normal risk-neutral fashion but we have a new kid on the block who looked at this and asked the question.

If there is no options market yet for this spread option, then the risk- neutral dynamics for the floating strike is whatever you want it to be. Risk-neutrality basically means no arbitrage, but if there is no options market and the floating strike is not even tradable, who is going to arbitrage you? As to your second question: you can look at historical EBITDA volatility if available, and its correlation to stock price if possible, add a spread to be prudent, and use that to substantiate your pricing/valuation.
